# Build Apache on vista

Tags: apache, makefile, windows-vista, mod-proxy

I try to build Apache2.4.9 by MINGW on VISTA.

When I make it following messages are showed.

```
mod_proxy.c:2700:1: error: initializer element is not constant
In file included from c:/devel/apache/httpd-2.4.9/include/util_mutex.h:30:0,
                 from mod_proxy.h:47,
                 from mod_proxy.c:17:
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I configured it with following command line.

```
./configure --prefix=/c/opt/apache --with-apr=/c/opt/apache --with-apr-util=/c/opt/apache --with-pcre=/c/opt/pcre --with-ssl=/c/opt/openssl --disable-ratelimit --disable-mod_proxy
```

If I change to Apache2.4.7 and run make following messages are showed.

```
modules/generators/.libs/libmod_status.a(mod_status.o): In function `status_hand
ler':
c:\devel\apache\httpd-2.2.27\modules\generators/mod_status.c:825: undefined refe
rence to `_imp__ap_run_status_hook@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
```

I can't solve these.

Comment: What's vistapache ? And any specific reason why you want to build it instead of downloading a binary ?

Comment: The reason why I want to buid on vista is just charange.